# JavaFX how to change a letter color of a label?

Tags: java, javafx, label

I am trying to make a TypingGame. As you know, the target word letter colors have to change as soon as you type the correct words. Here you can see an example and also my code. I can not seem to make it work. I thought maybe I can make it with charAt or with append maybe. For now, the whole text color changes as soon as you type.

[image: example]

```
public class TypingGame extends Application {

    public static final EventType<KeyEvent> KEY_PRESSED = null;
    private List<String> words;
    private int currentIndex;
    private long startTime;
    private int correctCount;

    private Label wordLabel;
    private TextField inputField;
    private Label resultLabel;
    private Button startButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            loadWords();

            wordLabel = new Label();
            inputField = new TextField();
            resultLabel = new Label();
            startButton = new Button("Start Game");

            startButton.setOnAction(event -> startGame());

            inputField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    checkWord();
                }
            });

            VBox root = new VBox(10);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.getChildren().addAll(wordLabel, inputField, resultLabel, startButton);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Typing Game");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent event) -> {
                String typedWord = inputField.getText().trim();
                String targetWord = words.get(currentIndex);

                if (typedWord.length() <= targetWord.length()) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < typedWord.length(); i++) {
                        if (typedWord.charAt(i) == targetWord.charAt(i)) {
                            wordLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                            correctCount++;
                        } else {
                            wordLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void startGame() {
        Collections.shuffle(words);
        currentIndex = 0;
        correctCount = 0;
        showNextWord();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        inputField.setDisable(false);
        startButton.setDisable(true);
        resultLabel.setText("");
    }

    private void showNextWord() {
        if (currentIndex < words.size()) {
            wordLabel.setText(words.get(currentIndex));
            wordLabel.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            inputField.clear();
        } else {
            endGame();
        }
    }

    private void checkWord() {
        String typedWord = inputField.getText().trim();
        String targetWord = words.get(currentIndex);

        if (typedWord.equals(targetWord)) {
            wordLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            correctCount++;
        } else {
            wordLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        }

        wordLabel.setText(targetWord);
        currentIndex++;
        showNextWord();
    }

    private void endGame() {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        inputField.setDisable(true);
        startButton.setDisable(false);

        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        int wordsPerMinute = calculateWordsPerMinute(elapsedTime);

        resultLabel.setText("Game Over!\nWPM: " + wordsPerMinute + "\nAverage WPM: " + calculateAverageWPM());
    }

    private int calculateWordsPerMinute(long elapsedTime) {
        int wordCount = words.size();
        long minutes = elapsedTime / 60000; // 1 minute = 60,000 milliseconds
        double wpm = (double) correctCount / minutes;

        return (int) wpm;
    }

    private double calculateAverageWPM() {
        int totalWPM = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++) {
            totalWPM += calculateWordsPerMinute(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }

        return totalWPM / (double) currentIndex;
    }

    private void loadWords() {
        words = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File selectedFile = new File(("dictionary/english.txt"));

            if (selectedFile != null) {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        words.add(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Handle case where no file is selected
                System.out.println("No file selected.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what a [`TextFlow`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) is for.  Oracle [provides a tutorial on its usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-settings.htm).

Comment: I saw a gradient looking text but just asking to be sure, I can change letter by letter of a text right?

Comment: Yes, example 39-12 in the Oracle Tutorial, demonstrates how to change the color of different text parts in a `TextFlow`.  It's not a `Label`, there *is no equivalent support for multicolored text in a `Label`*.